# Why can't I close the window handle in my code?

Tags: c, winapi

I have these two lines in my main, but I can not close the the handle in the end.
I am trying to get a handle to windows mines weeper and close it after that, but it doesn't work. And I have all the relevant includes I need.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

in the main

```
HWND wh = FindWindow("Minesweeper", "Minesweeper");
CloseHandle(wh);
```

On the `printf` of `wh` I see the value is identical to this raised in spy++.

And I'm getting the error

> "Exception address: 0x7c90e4ff"

What am I missing?

BTW:
Closing Handle of a process works fine if I change the two lines above.

Comment: Is `wh` null when you call CloseHandle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of basic problems here. First of all you don't call `CloseHandle` with a window handle. It's not that kind of handle. You use `CloseHandle` when you have a `HANDLE` but an `HWND` is not a `HANDLE`. If you want to destroy a window handle you need to call `DestroyWindow`.

However, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `DestroyWindow` states:

> A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread.

So you can't do that either.

What you can do is to send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the window. That should be enough to persuade it to close gracefully.

Note that `WM_CLOSE` is sent rather than posted. This can be discerned by this line from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A window receives this message through its WindowProc function.

**Update**

John Knoller points out that I am misinterpreting the Windows documentation which was not written to cover the situation where one application attempts to close down another application.

John's advice is:

> In fact it's wiser to send `WM_CLOSE` to another process using `PostMessage` or `SendNotifyMessage`. If you use `SendMessage`, you will get stuck if the process isn't pumping messages. It's even better to use `WM_SYSCOMMAND`/`SCCLOSE` which is basically the same thing as clicking on the window caption's close button.

Comment: You are misreading that last line. In fact it's wiser to send WM_CLOSE to another process using PostMessage or SendNotifyMessage  If you use SendMessage, you will get stuck if the process isn't pumping messages.  It's even better to use WM_SYSCOMMAND/SCCLOSE which is basically the same thing as clicking on the window caption's close button.

Comment: @John OK, I'll update. But just so that I am clear, and out of interest, how does Windows deliver the message without getting stuck?

Comment: you mean the click on the close button message? that's just a WM_NCMOUSECLICK message 'posted' to the thread's message queue. user input events are always put in the thread's queue using a post-like mechanism. (it's not actually post message).  It only gets turned into a WM_SYSCOMMAND/NCCLOSE when the thread calls GetMessage()/DispatchMessage().

Comment: @John So WM_CLOSE is actually delivered to the window by the default window proc when it handles WM_SYSCOMMAND?

Comment: Sort of, Most applications pass WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_CLOSE to DefWindowProc. DefWindowProc then turns it into a WM_CLOSE message. If a WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_CLOSE doesn't result in a WM_CLOSE message, then the app made a special effort to make that happen and you should respect it.

Comment: You can use `SendMessageTimeout` safely and you will not hang on unresponsive window.

Comment: _A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread._ In fact, you can. You can inject your code into another process and call `DestroyWindow` to close SPECIFIC window, and not just kill whole app with `WM_CLOSE`, like in your solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Do not** use [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`CloseWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Send a [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the window using [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Any reason why not posting `WM_CLOSE`?

Comment: @Deanna PostMessage is also fine. The reason I usually use SendMessage, is that it waits for the window procedure of the target window to handle the message. So after SendMessage returns, you can immediately check whether the target window is really closed.

Comment: Isn't that just an icky, equivalent alternative to CloseWindow()?

Comment: @Lundin CloseWindow minimizes (but does not destroy) the specified window.

Comment: Aah fair enough... Rephrase: isn't that just an icky, equivalent alternative to DestroyWindow()?  :)

Comment: I must be going crazy, the answer said to use DestroyWindow when I first read it.. Unless SO changed the order of the replies and I didn't notice. :|

Comment: @Lundin See David's post above: "A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread."

Comment: @Deanna I suggested using either DestroyWindow or SendMessage with WM_CLOSE, but DestroyWindow cannot be used from another thread or process, so I deleted that option. See David's post above.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I commented in the first place :)

Comment: @Deanna Sorry, I thought it was David Heffernan... Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 4):

Windows handles (HWNDs) are not system handles (HANDLEs).  CloseHandle() is for system objects.

Consider `PostMessage( wh, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0 );`, as [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893) describes.

Comment: Thanks for an actual example!! I'd forgotten what parameters to pass to `PostMessage()`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, [`EndModal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-enddialog) is a working solution:

```
HWND hWnd = GetWindow(Handle, GW_ENABLEDPOPUP);
EndDialog(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close specific sub-window of some other process, and not just kill whole process with `WM_CLOSE` you can [inject your code into another process](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) and call `DestroyWindow` from there. This will also let you close windows that are specifically ignoring `WM_CLOSE` messages or not responding.